# Unable to integrate AdMob ads in my Android app

Tags: android, admob

I've been following the instructions from the AdMob site (here:https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en) and I'm still unable to get the ads to work, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong.

Here's my Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:background="@drawable/bg_maple"
>
[...]

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     ads:adUnitId="my real unit id from admob"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, my real device id"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
[...]
```

And in my Activity:

```
public class Banner extends Activity {
      private AdView adView;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "my real unit id from admob");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        adRequest.addTestDevice("Here I have my device ID");
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm stuck and don't seem to be able to see what's wrong at the moment.

Note: my unit id, and the device id are both added correctly to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using two separate AdView, the first from your xml and the second from code. please try to change your code

```
public class Banner extends Activity {
      private AdView adView;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create the adView
          adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
       // RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        // Add the adView to it
        //layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        adRequest.addTestDevice("Here I have my device ID");

      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! It works fine now. I am really ashamed that I missed such a big error on my behalf.